# Run the script on the server from the html page

Tags: express, fetch

I want some actions to be performed on the server by clicking a button on an html page. Express.js and fetch

```
//index.html

function f_loadForm(){
            fetch("http://localhost:3000/fileWithFunctions/function1()" )
         }
f_loadForm()
```

here I start the server

```
//server.js

function f1() {
   // starting the server
}

f1()
```

Comment: How is the latter code snippet in any way an Express web server?  Where/how are you mapping the route `/fileWithFunctions/function1()` to any server-side endpoint?  (And why are you including parentheses in the route?)  Additionally, what is your question?  What specifically isn't working in your code?  Please clarify the specific problem you are trying to solve.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I would suggest you need to read about [Express Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). In short, any route you perform a HTTP Request on can execute a script for you. The route handler in itself is a script being executed.

Comment: I wanted to write the full code of my function, but the site gave an error that there was too much code and not enough text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be as follows:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

function f1() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
}

app.get('/index.html', (req, res) => {
    // Standard html serving code
});

app.get('/f1', (req, res) => {
    f1(); // Call f1 here.
    res.send("Complete");
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer made it clear to me that in "fetch" does not specify a path, but a regular String. And in the server.js in app.get we describe what to do if this ordinary String is caught